# How to check if a range of values are in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list with two integers which can change randomly. I want to check if any of these integers are over `21`.

So for example if I wanted to find a specific integer I would say:

```
score = [4, 21]
if 21 in score:
   ...
```

However, how would I change this to a range of values instead of a specific integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you only have two numbers, simple conditional operators will suffice:

```
if score[0] > 21 or score[1] > 21:
```

Otherwise, if you have more numbers, you can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression):

```
if any(x > 21 for x in score):
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try it this way (using `any`):

```
score = [4, 21]
integers = [21,43]
if any(i > max(score) for i in integers):
    ...
```

The integers can be an iterable of any length, say `[2,3,1,6,7]`. It'll check them one at a time to verify if it satisfies the condition that `i > max(score)`. The first one that does will short-circuit the result to `True`. The code inside the condition then executes successfully.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `range`:

```
>>> s
[4, 21]
>>> 2 in range(s[0], s[1])
False
>>> 20 in range(s[0], s[1])
True
>>>
```

If your list is not ordered, you have to add `s.sort()` before proceeding with the use of `range`

Comment: This assumes that s only contains exactly two numbers that are ordered.

Comment: And it is a correct assumption. Read the first sentence of the OP's question: "I have a list with two integers which can change randomly..." ordering them would only require an additional `s.sort()`

Comment: Ideally you would look for a slightly more general solution. And why would you create a list of arbitrary numbers and compare your target to all of them? If `s[0] == 1` and `s[1] == 21`, there is no reason to create a list of 20 numbers and compare a target value to each member of that list. See iCodez's solution using Python's `any`.

Comment: I don't think the use of `any` is suitable for a beginner. The use of `range` might not be very efficient but it doesn't introduce a new keyword. Your own answer also shows a misunderstanding of what is being asked and is unnecessarily difficult for a newbie, IMO.

Answer (score -1):

You might look into using a `Set`.

```
score = set([4, 21, 8, 10, 22, 12])
target= set([21, 22])

if target.issubset(score):
    ...
```